# Preventing Line Breaks Before and After a text field in JQuery Mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to create three controls that are layed out horizontally. In an attempt to accomplish this, I'm currently trying the following:

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
  <input id="button1" type="button" value="<" />
  <span><input id="tally1" type="text" /></span>
  <input id="button2" type="button" value=">" />
</div>
```

This text input field seems to insert a line break before and after itself. If I remove the text field, everything lays out as expected. How do I get rid of the line break? If I can't, how do I layout these three fields in a horizontal stack?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
#tally1 {
    display:inline;
}
```

Try changing `display:inline;` to `display:inline !important;` It may be that the text field is inheriting a display style from JQuery Mobile, you'd use `!important` to override it, but only as a last resort.

Comment: @user 70192: Well, start out by getting rid of that extra `<span>`. Are your text inputs styled in any way in your CSS?

Comment: i did get rid of the <span>. as mentioned, I'm using JQuery mobile. I'm wondering if there is some magic there that is preventing this from working.

Comment: @user70192: see my edited answer. That's the only thing I can think of.

Answer (score 3):

To prevent a line break after text, the field FOLLOWING the text has to have "display:inline !important;".

Also, for some reason which may be corrected after the (current to this post) jquery mobile v1.20, the heights of select and text-inputs are not quite right and need a cryptic mix of padding and margins resetting to work.

The "!important" specs were required in the following fiddle.  Here is a list with 2 lines - one aligned to normal buttons and one to the mini buttons.  Good Luck!

See http://jsfiddle.net/RM5eq/

```
    <style>
.floatleft {
float:left;
 }
.floatright {
float:right;
 }
.forceinline{  /* Prevent fieldcontain from doing a BLOCK thing */
display:inline !important;
}
.textwidth {  /* limit width of input fields */
width:80px;
}
.closespacing { /* controls spacing between elements */
margin:0px 5px 0px 0px;
 }
.bigselect {   /* centers select with big buttons */
padding: 0px;
margin:2px 5px 0px 0px;
 }
.biginputheight {   /* matches text input height to big buttons */
padding-top:10px !important;
padding-bottom:12px !important;
}
.miniinputheight { /* matches text input height to minibuttons */
padding-top:5px !important;
padding-bottom:5px !important;
}
</style>
<div data-role="page" class="type-home">
```

```
<ul data-role="listview">
  <li  data-role="fieldcontain">first LI line</li>
  <li  data-role="fieldcontain">

    <div class='floatleft closespacing'>
        Big Buttons<br>More Text
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class= 'forceinline'>
      <div class='floatleft closespacing'>    
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
          <input type="radio" name="radio-view" id="radio-view-a" value="aa"  />
          <label for="radio-view-a">A1</label>
          <input type="radio" name="radio-view" id="radio-view-b" value="bb"  />
          <label for="radio-view-b">B1</label>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div  class='floatleft bigselect'>    
      <select name="select-choice-0" id="select-choice-1" data-inline="true" class=' '>
        <option >SM1</option>
        <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div  class='floatleft textwidth'>
      <input type="text" placeholder="left" class='biginputheight'></input>
    </div>  

    <div  class='floatright textwidth'>
      <input type="text" placeholder="right" class='biginputheight'></input>
    </div>  

  </li>
  <li  data-role="fieldcontain">

    <div class='floatleft closespacing'>    
        Small Buttons
    </div>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class= 'forceinline'>
      <div class='floatleft closespacing'>    
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini='true'>
          <input type="radio" name="radio-view" id="radio-view-a" value="aa"  />
          <label for="radio-view-a">AA</label>
          <input type="radio" name="radio-view" id="radio-view-b" value="bb"  />
          <label for="radio-view-b">BB</label>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div  class='floatleft textwidth'>
      <input type="text" placeholder="e2" class='miniinputheight'></input>
    </div>  

    <div  class='floatleft closespacing'>
      <select name="select-choice-2" id="select-choice-2" data-inline="true" data-mini='true'>
        <option >SM2</option>
        <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
      </select>
    </div>       

    <div class='floatright closespacing'>
      <div  class='floatright closespacing'>    
        e3 Text<br>on right
      </div>
      <div  class='floatright textwidth'>
        <input type="text" placeholder="e3" class='miniinputheight'></input>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </li>
  <li  data-role="fieldcontain">last LI line</li>

</ul><!-- /listview -->
```